# GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable return SERVICE_VERSION UPDATE REQUIRED but my Google Play Services is already updated

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-maps-v2

I'm using Motorola Defy with Android Version 2.2.1.
My app use GoogleMaps Api V2. Before using maps, I check if everything is ok with GooglePlayServices with this method:

```
public static boolean checkIfMapsIsOk(Activity context) {
    int checkGooglePlayServices =    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { 
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices, context, 1122).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This method always return ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, but I've checked my Google Play Services is updated. How can I solve this situation??

Thanks.

Comment: you say it is up to date but what is the actual version you have and what version of google play services are you using?

Comment: getErrorDialog redirect me to Google Play app in the page of Google Play Services app, and there is no update option, just Open and Uninstall. Another important information: In others devices my app  works perfectly.

Comment: yes but when you look on your device in your apps what version of google play services do you have on your device...just because it says you dont have an update does not mean you are up to date. you say that you have a phone on 2.2 well google dropped support for 2.2 in google play services 4.0 and if you are using google play services 4.0 in your project you will get the error saying you are not up to date because you dont have that version

Comment: Hmmm ok,  my google play services version is 3.2.66. Do you have a tip to update it? Because Google Play doesn't help me. =[

Comment: you cant update you google play services on your phone, I just said google dropped support for 2.2 in the new version and only works on 2.3 and up. you need to use google play services for froyo which is available to download in the ADT. You will never see the new google play service update

Comment: Hmm ok, I try run again now with Google Play Services for Froyo as library and my app work fine this time. Thank you!